# Including dependencies in Java project on Intellij/Maven?

Tags: java, dependencies, dependency-management

This sounds dumb but is there anyway for me to specify dependencies for my Java project like how I would in a package.json file so that someone else who was to download the project code from my GitHub repo, would be able to run it without any errors or missing libraries?

I have never tried using external Java libraries before, such as apache commons. The most I ever used was JavaFX but on a personal project level. My main concern is that if I were to push my code up to the repo and have someone else clone it. It might not run properly as the imported libraries are not downloaded.

Is there something similar to package.json dependencies where the person who runs the code would automatically download all dependency libraries and have it run on their system?

Comment: Yes. This is what maven is used for

Comment: Sily question here: Do I have to remove the xml file from gitignore for it to work?

Comment: If you are referring to pom.xml, yes it should be present in your git repo

Comment: Aight! Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Maven or Gradle for this purpose. Maven has pom.xml where you can specify all your dependencies. Similarly gradle has build.gradle which does the same job.